# Conversion from english to morse,and then to binary- code doesn't display anything

Tags: c++

I have to translate online some sentences ( the commented ones), I am trying now with simpler one. I have to translate in morse and then in specific a binary code, I don't know why the code doesn't display anything! /[here](http://cpp.sh/7pevt) the url on c++ shell
(I have to do it online because I have to do some tasks with this binary code and I have to save memory)
P.S.
Do you have some advices for a better code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string morseCode[26] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", 
    "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", 
    ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", 
    "-.--", "--.."};
    //char tweets[5][65]={"A FEATHER IN THE HAND IS BETTER THAN A BIRD IN THE AIR","A SHORT PENCIL IS USUALLY BETTER THAN A LONG MEMORY ANY DAY","ACCEPT SOMETHING THAT YOU CANNOT CHANGE AND YOU WILL FEEL BETTER","ADVENTURE CAN BE REAL HAPPINESS","ALL THE EFFORT YOU ARE MAKING WILL ULTIMATELY PAY OFF"};
  std::vector<std::string> tweets = {"AB C ","OK "}; 
    char ch;
    string  morseWord;
    static int riga=0;
    char binary_out=' ';
 for (riga=0;riga<1;riga++){
   for( int i=0;i<6;i++){
        
    if (tweets[riga][i]==' '){
        binary_out=binary_out+'0000';
     }
    else
        {   morseWord="";
            cout<<"morse"<<morseWord;
            ch = tweets[riga][i];
            morseWord = morseWord+ morseCode[ch - 'A']; 
        
            cout<<morseWord;
            for (int k=0;k<morseWord.length();k++){
                if(morseWord[k]=='.')
                binary_out=binary_out+'10';
                if(morseWord[k]=='-')
                binary_out=binary_out+'1110';
                
        }
        binary_out=binary_out+'00';
    }
   }
```

Comment: Your example does not compile. Please provide a working one.

Comment: Please review your C++ textbook, a `char` variable will only ever be able to contain a single letter. Use a `std::string` instead.

Comment: but if I write `std::string tweets[2][7]` I have problems when checking  if the i-element of the raw is a blankspace, here `if (tweets[riga][i]==' ')`

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> tweets = {"AB C ","OK "};`

Comment: Ok I have updated it, thank you to everyone, but it still doesn't display anything..

Comment: `binary_out` should be a string. Follow the compiler warnings

Comment: You keep saying that your program does not display anything. I would like to double-check that. Is it true that you never see `"morse"` displayed? (Precision is important when debugging.) A good debugging question should include the actual output (copy-and-paste), not your interpretation of the output. It should also have the expected output, which would help us deduce if your multi-character character literals are intended to be string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I think your approach and logic is flawed. I do not know what your code is trying to do so I can not explain where it is wrong, but I rewrote what I assumed you were trying to do.

As for advice for better code.
These are all my personal preference:

- Get rid of `using namespace std`. There are lots of reasons you can find out why.
- Use `std::array` instead of a C array for storing the morse code as `std::array` has bounds checking which would let you know that it goes out of bounds trying to find '\0'.
- Use functions to seperate your code into little sections.
- Be consistant with the way you name variables, you have `morseCode` which is camel case, then you have `binary_out` which is snake case.
- Do not declare variables until you use them.
- Have descriptive variable names, I have no idea what `riga` means.
- Do not assume the size of a `std::string` or any container, use `std::string::size()`, or an iterator.
- Use comments to explain what your code is doing and why.

Here is my rewritten code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

/// returns morse code and space
/// \param character space or [A, Z]
std::string getMorse(const char character) {
    // if character is a space, a long space
    if (character == ' ') {
        return "   ";
    }
    // otherwise, character is in range [A, Z], return morse for character
    const std::array<std::string, 26> morse_code{
        ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---",
        "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-",
        "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "--.."
    };
    // remember to add a space to seperate the character
    return morse_code.at(character - 'A') + ' ';
}

/// returns binary
/// \param morse_character '.' OR '-' OR ' ', otherwise empty string returned
std::string getBinary(const char morse_character) {
    switch (morse_character) {
    case '.':
        return "10";
        break;
    case '-':
        return "1110";
        break;
    case ' ':
        return "00";
        break;
    }
    return "";
}

int main() {
    /// tweets to convert to morse code and binary
    const std::array<std::string, 2> tweets{ "AB C ","OK " };
    // go through each tweet
    for (const auto& tweet : tweets) {
        // create empty strings for binary and morse
        std::string binary_out;
        std::string morse_out;
        // go through each character in tweet
        for (const char character : tweet) {
            // get morse code for character
            const auto morse = getMorse(character);
            // add morse code to morse string
            morse_out += morse;
            // go through each character in morse code
            for (const char morse_character : morse) {
                // convert morse character to binary and add to binary string
                binary_out += getBinary(morse_character);
            }
        }
        // once all characters in tweet have been evaluated, output morse and binary
        std::cout << "morse:\t" << morse_out << std::endl;
        std::cout << "binary:\t" << binary_out << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
morse:  .- -...    -.-.
binary: 1011100011101010100000000011101011101000000000
morse:  --- -.-
binary: 11101110111000111010111000000000
```

---

Edit: Index based for loops

```cpp
// go through each tweet
for (size_t tweet_index = 0; tweet_index < tweets.size(); ++tweet_index) {
    const auto& tweet = tweets[tweet_index];
    ...
    // go through each character in tweet
    for (size_t character_index = 0; character_index < tweet.size(); ++character_index) {
        const char character = tweet[character_index];
```

This will have `tweet_index` as the index in the tweet array, and `character_index` as the index in the character array.

Comment: Start with saying: the output you had is the one I would like to have too.
I am very greatful for this answer and for each advice you patiently give to me (I found myself coding in c++ without any notice!). Anyway, I have understood your code and learn new things about the language but, in practice, I have to add this in eclipse with osek language so I have to deal with periodic tasks. I want to translate a character of my tweet, updating manually an index (static int) that goes to the next character and then finish my task.

Comment: How can your code be modified to deal with index in two of for loops (  the one through each tweet and the one through each character)? I mean, in eclipse I will remove these 2 for loops and I will introduce a static index that at the end of the task will be updated like index++; I hope this make sense for you!

Comment: @etnamaid I have added an edit to the bottom of my post that shows an example of how to use indexes for the for loops.