# Memory problem, converting string into char and getting this " invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'"

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where it is very important to save memory. I have done this function ( truly not me, but a guy in a question I did some days ago [Conversion from english to morse,and then to binary- code doesn't display anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821485/conversion-from-english-to-morse-and-then-to-binary-code-doesnt-display-anythi?noredirect=1#comment114608155_64821485) ),

```
String getMorse( char character) {
      // if character is a space, a long space
      if (character == ' ') {
          return " ";
      }
      // otherwise, character is in range [A, Z], return morse for character
     static char morse_code[27][5]={
          ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---",
          "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-",
          "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "--.."
      };
      // remember to add a space to seperate the character
      return morse_code[character - 'A'] ;
  }
```

but I dont want to use Strings because they occupy a lot of memory so I want to use character, and  I modified the code like this

```
  char getMorse( char character) {
      // if character is a space, a long space
      if (character == ' ') {
          return ' ';
      }
      // otherwise, character is in range [A, Z], return morse for character
     static char morse_code[27][5]={
          ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---",
          "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-",
          "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "--.."
      };
      // remember to add a space to seperate the character
      return morse_code[character - 'A'] ;
  }
```

And I get this error!

> error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
>    return morse_code[character - 'A'] ;
> ```

The thing I want to do when I call the function is
 `auto morse = getMorse(character) + ' ';` So I want to add a space after the morse.. (This function translate into morse only one character at a time)

Comment: The `morse_code` array contains `const char*` elements, not `char`.

Comment: a `char` is a single character. Why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: ".. because they occupy a lot of memory" where did you get this from? A `std::string` contains characters and what you need to keep track of its size. Whoever told you that it uses "a lot of memory" didn't know what they were talking about

Comment: What is `String` ?

Comment: "..a guy in this forum" please provide a link to the originial post. (and SO is not a forum)

Comment: I can't use std::string because i have to use eclipse and it gives me a lot of errors, Strings instead compiles

Comment: you need to include `<string>`, maybe you made other mistakes, but your ide should have no impact on whether you can use `std::string` or not

Comment: The Morse code for the character 'A' is not a single character. If you optimize that code into a character, you've broken your functionality. Don't optimize away correct functionality.

Comment: *"I dont want to use Strings because they occupy a lot of memory"* combined with space wasting `char morse_code[27][5]` seems to be at odds.

Comment: I have tried to include string but eclipse can't find the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
char morse_code[27][5]
```

defines `morse_code` as a two-dimensional array of `char` elements. Or (maybe a more precise definition) an array whose elements are arrays of 5 `char` elements.

If you take one element of the 2-D array using code like `morse_code[...]`, it will be a 5-element array of `char`. In C++, any array can be converted to a pointer to its first element, in this case, `char*`. So a correct return type to your `getMorse` function is `char*`, and not `char`. Note that `char*` is the type which C (and also sometimes C++) uses for strings.

Another correct return type could be `char[5]`, but the syntax for using that is too confusing, so most people use `char*` instead.

BTW you could also return `const char*`, to prevent incorrect usage of the returned value.

---

If you want to save memory, you should represent your morse-code using bits: holding one byte whose value can be only `-` or `.` is too wasteful.

Comment: How can I represent my morse using bits? What do you mean?

Comment: If you "dont want to use Strings because they occupy a lot of memory", you could make one more step, and wonder what occupies even less memory than your solution. The next step is, represent each morse code symbol by one bit. This is a bit pointless, because your table of codes is already very small, even if you use `std::string` for it. But could be a fun exercise; we even have a [whole site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) dedicated for [exercises like this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19121/25315).

Comment: *"holding one byte whose value can be only `-` or `.` is too wasteful."* -- actually, there are three relevant values: `'-'`, `'.'`, and `'\0'` (the last because the strings are different lengths). The principle is sound, though, and you could still represent each letter's Morse code in a single byte (either two bits per symbol or use half the byte to hold the length).